# Get field_ id from BuddyPress profile fields in extended profile

Tags: php, wordpress, get

I can get a profiles avatar and name by this code:

```
?php echo get_avatar(1); ?>

            <?php 
                $user_id = 1;
                $key = 'first_name';
                $single = true;
                $user_first = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $single ); 
                echo '<span>' . '' . $user_first . '</span>'; 
            ?>
```

But then I also have BuddyPress installed and trying to get the new fields that I created there. I identified the id on one of the field to `fields_2`

This is what I have written that don't work:

```
<?php 
            $user_id = 1;
            $key = 'field_2';
            $single = true;
            $user_field = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $single ); 
            echo '<span>' . '' . $user_field . '</span>'; 
        ?>
```

How can I get this `field_2` from the extended BuddyPress field?

Answer (score 0):

Check your database if it actually has "field_2", your code should work fine. but you can also try using it inside the bp user loop and also replace get_user_meta with bp_get_user_meta. It works better with some buddy press plugins.

```
if ( bp_has_members() ) {
    while ( bp_members() ) {
        bp_the_member();
        $user_last = bp_get_user_meta( bp_get_member_user_id(), 'field_2', true );
    }
}
```

Comment: Bah, been trying and trying without any luck... Where can i find that in the database? 

I don't really know how to add that if state:

<?php 
if ( bp_has_members() ) {
    while ( bp_members() ) {
        bp_the_member();
        $user_last = bp_get_user_meta( bp_get_member_user_id(), 'field_2', true );
    }
}
?>

Comment: checkout your user meta table. Use this select query to search, SELECT * FROM wp_usermeta WHERE userid = $userid and then search the results for 'field_2'

Comment: This is hard can't find anything... maybe I'm doing wrong... The second thing you did here above, how do I enter a "if" state and where
<?php
if ( bp_has_members() ) {
    while ( bp_members() ) {
        bp_the_member();
        $user_last = bp_get_user_meta( bp_get_member_user_id(), 'field_2', true );
    }
}
?>

Comment: This made it work! Hope it's right :) Thank you for guiding!

$field = xprofile_get_field_data(2, $user_id); 
echo '' . $field . '';